# Верстка в ie8, неправильные шрифты, и размеры блоков

Tags: шрифты, internet-explorer, вёрстка, css

**[Вот так выглядит на IE10](http://www.imgup.ru/image-16d4x1681949.html)**

**[А на IE8](http://www.imgup.ru/image-16d5x52017310.html)**

Как видно по рисунку поменялся шрифт и его размер из за этого не влазит в меню, вопрос как уменьшит этот размер? а так же как потерялся текст в placeholdere?

1. Как вариант пытался подключить отдельно стили для IE9 и ниже, но они не подключились o_O

   ```
   <link href="../css/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style_ie.css"  type="text/css" /<![endif]-->
   ```
2. с плейсхолдерем пытался поступить так

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
   /* Placeholder for IE */
   if($.browser.msie) { // Условие для вызова только в IE
       $("form").find("input[type='text']").each(function() {
           var tp = $(this).attr("placeholder");
           $(this).attr('value',tp).css('color','#ccc');
       }).focusin(function() {
           var val = $(this).attr('placeholder');
           if($(this).val() == val) {
               $(this).attr('value','').css('color','#303030');
           }
       }).focusout(function() {
           var val = $(this).attr('placeholder');
           if($(this).val() == "") {
               $(this).attr('value', val).css('color','#ccc');
           }
       });

       /* Protected send form */
       $("form").submit(function() {
           $(this).find("input[type='text']").each(function() {
               var val = $(this).attr('placeholder');
               if($(this).val() == val) {
                   $(this).attr('value','');
               }
           })
       });
   }
   });
   </script>
   ```

   но не получилось :(

Comment: placeholder в ie8-ie9 не работает http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/placeholder

http://www.xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/html5-and-css3/jquery-placeholder.html - это вариант как это исправить

Comment: по поводу шрифтов - Браузеры рендерят шрифты по разному, 100% сходства вы можете не увидеть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стили не подключились, потому что у вас была ошибка в разметке.
В условном комментарии вы не закрывали тэг link.
Исправьте код:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style_ie.css"  type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
```

Comment: блин внатуре) но вопрос стоял в том что на ie8 шрифт отображается не корректно 
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OswaldRegular';
    src: url('-g5pdusrgvxvol5u-a_whw.eot');
    src: url('-g5pdusrgvxvol5u-a_whw.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('-g5pdusrgvxvol5u-a_whw.woff') format('woff'),
         url('-g5pdusrgvxvol5u-a_whw.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('-g5pdusrgvxvol5u-a_whw.svg#OswaldRegular') format('svg');
}

Comment: @reddyk, соберите пример на jsFiddle, будет проще ответить

Answer (score 1):

Касательно placeholder. Ваш код работает только для элементов типа `input`, поскольку использует соответствующий селектор и `.attr('value')` вместо `.val()`. Кроме того, `$.browser` — это устаревшее свойство. Исправленный код:

```
if(!('placeholder' in document.createElement('input'))){
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form").find("input[type='text'], textarea").each(function() {
        var tp = $(this).attr("placeholder");
        $(this).val(tp).css('color','#ccc');
    }).focusin(function() {
        var val = $(this).attr('placeholder');
        if($(this).val() == val) {
            $(this).val('').css('color','#303030');
        }
    }).focusout(function() {
        var val = $(this).attr('placeholder');
        if($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val(val).css('color','#ccc');
        }
    });
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $(this).find("input[type='text'], textarea").each(function() {
            var val = $(this).attr('placeholder');
            if($(this).val() == val) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        })
    });
});
}
```

Comment: да я примерно такое же решение принял)